# Extract index values from groupby using numpy array

Tags: numpy, group-by, filtering

I'm trying to extract 7 rows of data grouped by the DTY column in a Dataframe. I think I need to use a numpy array to filter, but can't seem to get it working.

Here's an extract of my original CLimate_DF dataframe (note there are NaN values for the :

Year    Month   Day DTY Precip9am    MaxT    ...    Wind ms 21 hr
1989    1   1   1   0        29.7    ...    0
1989    1   2   2   0        31.1    ...    4.6
1989    1   3   3   0.4      32      ...    2.1
... ... ... ... ...      ...     ...    ...
2019    12  31  365 21.2         31.3    ...    2.1

First, I created a numpy array filter based on a given date - this works and creates the right array:

#Enter Day of Interest (DOI) yyyy, mm, dd

```
DOI = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 6)
DTY = DOI.timetuple()[7]
DTYMinus3 = DTY-3
DTYPlus3 = DTY+3
DTY_Array = np.linspace(DTYMinus3, DTYPlus3,7)
DTY_Array = np.array(DTY_Array)
```

I now want to extract all values from all years for columns 'Precip9am' through to 'Winds ms 21 hr' and filter those columns to just include DTY = DTY_Array

I've grouped the Climate_DF to DTY and then try to apply a filter:
ClimateDTY_DF = Climate_DF.groupby("DTY")
DTY_Climate = ClimateDTY_DF[DTY_Array]

I get the following error:
KeyError: 'Columns not found: 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0'

```
I'm assuming this is because the filter is trying to find the values in the ClimateDTY_DF columns, but I need **it to be filtering through the DTY column to find all the indexes from the array and extract the values from each column aftern 'Precip9am'**. 

How do I do this? Do I transpose first? Or do I need to create some kind of loop that creates a DF for DTY and each column from 'Precip9am' through to 'Winds ms 21 hr' and extracts just the DTY from the array for each?
```